# jQuery selection - filter numbers, quotes, and first space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension the accesses data on multiple websites to create lists of the data. One site in particular is very awkward with the way their data is presented. I am currently using the following method to filter data I need on all other sites:

```
addThings: function (elemone, elemtwo, elemthree) {
        var self = this;
        $(elemone).each(function(i, el) {
            var values = $(elemtwo, this).text();
            if ($(elemthree, this).text().indexOf('2') >= 0){
                self.list.push(values);
            }
            self.list.push(values);
        });
    },
```

The problem herein lies with the fact that the data from this particular website is as follows:

> "2 Some Value"

Within the same exact block of HTML code/text/etc as plaintext, unlike the other websites.

I need to grab

> Some Value

and the number 2 separately. The value variable needs to equal Some Value, and the elemthree portion needs to grab the two. elemthree

The number will always be either 1 or 2, but Some Value can sometimes contains the number 7. How do I go about filtering it in a way that it doesn't break compatibility with other websites?

**EDIT**: Sorry if this is confusing... let me try to clarify. Most of the websites have the value I need from elemthree nested in its own DIV or CLASS. This one website has the elemtwo value I need and elemthree value in the same exact DIV/CLASS in plaintext, no separation whatsoever.

Example Site 1:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="myvalue">Some Value</div>
    <div class="myothervalue">2</div>
</div>
```

Here I simply have elemtwo set to .myvalue and elemthree to .myother value. I can use this code to grab the data I need.

```
addThings('#main','.myvalue','.myothervalue');
```

Example Site 2:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="bothvalues">"2 Some Value"</div>
</div>
```

Here it is difficult for me to properly seperate them from a long list of values without having an exception for this website, which I am trying to avoid by making my code compatible with both site so I can later on add new websites as needed. I can grab the number "2" just fine, but grabbing "Some Value" (including the space), without also grabbing the quotations and the 2 is difficult.

I believe what I am looking for is some regex to filter the '"2 ' bit - check if there is anything before the first alphabetic character and ignore it.

Comment: It's little unclear to me...

Comment: Tried to clarify it a little. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
addThings: function (elemone, elemtwo, elemthree) {
    var self = this;
    $(elemone).each(function(i, el) {
        if (elemthree){
            var values = $(elemtwo, this).text();
            if ($(elemthree, this).text().indexOf('2') >= 0){
                self.list.push(values);
            }
            self.list.push(values);
        }
        else {
           var v = $(elemtwo, this).text();
           var spaceIndex = v.indexOf(' ');
           var digit = v.substring(1, spaceIndex);
           var someValue = v.substring(spaceIndex, v.length - spaceIndex + 1);
           if (digit === '2'){
               self.list.push(someValue);
           }
        }
    });
},
```

Then you can call

```
addThings('#main','.bothvalues');
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution that is universal to all the sites involved. The most common cases are the examples I used above, and I'd like one function to work for both without "breaking the mold" so to speak. I believe instead of "hacking" in exceptions, I need a RegEx expression to extract the data I need.

Comment: Fair enough. Not sure what kind of extension you're writing but when I tried to write similar tools in the past I found that there's no universal solution, one site will have 3 divs, another 2 divs, with different classes, or no class, or an existing site will change from 3 divs to 2 divs the next week, etc, so I couldn't find a single solution to work for all sites. Instead I had to implement a solution similar to what I posted here, something that works for different sites, or a hack as you called it. Hope you find a universal solution though, keep us posted if you do.